# How to find a temp directory in dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, docker-machine, docker-registry

The Docker host is running a container named pine. How can i find a name of the file in the pine container's /tmp directory.

I tried to find inside /var/docker/containers but not able to find out

Answer (score 1):

You can run `ls` to see the contains of the `tmp` folder using:

```
docker run -it pine ls /tmp
```